# Transparent mysql_error logging: How can I read mysql_error() twice?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do a transparent mysql_error logging in my php app. I've done the following yet:

```
function mysql_query_log_error($query) {
    $debug_trace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
    $caller = $debug_trace[1];
    $file = substr($caller[file], strrpos($caller[file], '/')+1);
    $line = $caller[line];
    $error = mysql_error();

    $error_query = "INSERT INTO Common.ERRsql SET "
        ."errQuery = '".mysql_real_escape_string($query)."', "
        ."errText  = '".mysql_real_escape_string($error)."', "
        ."errDate  = NOW(), "
        ."errFile = '".mysql_real_escape_string($file)."', "
        ."errLine = '".mysql_real_escape_string($line)."' ";
    mysql_query($error_query);

}

function mysql_query_log($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query) or mysql_query_log_error($query);
    return $result;
}
```

But when I read `mysql_error()` in the `mysql_query_log_error()` function, the original caller can't access the `mysql_error()` (because it returns an empty string, so it's "read out").

How can I do it in a transparent way, I mean, the `mysql_error()` will remain intact?

Comment: don't you think that using the same storage that just produced an error is not too wise?

Comment: well yes, but most of the errors came from wrong SQL statements (table name changed, columns changed, unproper string handling, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You assign the original error to a variable, then pass that variable into the function. There's no need trying to duplicate the error, when you can get it once and store it in a variable.

Comment: But in this way, I have to change the original caller code, to grab the error message from the variable. But, well yes, I could change the `mysql_error()` in the same way to `mysql_error_my()` and handle a global variable in that.

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish what you're trying to do :

```
function mysql_query_log_error($query, $error) {
    $debug_trace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
    $caller = $debug_trace[1];
    $file = substr($caller[file], strrpos($caller[file], '/')+1);
    $line = $caller[line];

    $error_query = "INSERT INTO Common.ERRsql SET "
        ."errQuery = '".mysql_real_escape_string($query)."', "
        ."errText  = '".mysql_real_escape_string($error)."', "
        ."errDate  = NOW(), "
        ."errFile = '".mysql_real_escape_string($file)."', "
        ."errLine = '".mysql_real_escape_string($line)."' ";
    mysql_query($error_query);

}

function mysql_query_log($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query) or mysql_query_log_error($query, mysql_error());
    return $result;
}
```

In your mysql_query_log function, you will directly store the error in a variable.

Comment: No, I want to change `mysql_query()` calls in my app to `mysql_query_log()` without change in the original code. And some cases in the original code they use `mysql_query()or die(mysql_error())`, but if I change it to `mysql_query_log()or die(mysql_error())` the mysql_error() will return empty string, because I have read it out in `mysql_query_log_error()`